# PHP: How to get the main content of a website given by a RSS feed?

Tags: php, parsing, text, extract

I read some RSS feeds and they give as Text/News only a short peace of the Original Message.
I tried to take the given URL to original Article and try to get the content.
But i don't know how i can extract the relevant text part of the page.
Without Menu, Advertising, footer text etc.

Has anybody a idea how i can make this better?
Maybe there exists a PHP library which do this very good?
For example Facebook makes here a good job, when i post a link of my Websites (without any Facebook specific code), they detect the relevantt text part automatically.

Hope someone can help me a little bit.